# GitHub Not Accessible from Google Chrome

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, github

Whenever I try to go to GitHub through Google Chrome 11 I get the following error message:

[image: Chrome]

GitHub works perfectly fine in Firefox 4:

[image]

This has been going on for a few weeks. This is a fairly new install of Windows (I don't even remember if I've successfully got on to GitHub on this installation with Chrome in the past). I don't even use GitHub for hosting my own code personally, but this has proven annoying in that I can't even access other people's projects through Chrome!

Does anybody know what is going on here?

An interesting side note: [The Sight extension for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/epmaefhielclhlnmjofcdapbeepkmggh) doesn't work either! It worked on my old installation of Windows but not on this one. Is my Chrome installation just screwy? I've tried disabling certain other extensions but nothing seems to change.

Comment: Are you sure you aren't connecting through a proxy? Interestingly, somebody had the [same problem for GitHub](http://support.github.com/discussions/site/3300-site-not-displaying-in-chrome) but it has resolved itself.

Comment: Yea, I'm at home and I don't have any proxy stuff set up.

Comment: I have the same problem with chromium 69.0 :(

Comment: Same problem here with Chrome 72.0, fails with proxy (tried http and SOCKS proxies), works with direct internet connection, works with that same proxy using Firefox. Only thing that seems to work is to disable/reenable extensions at random

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok. So here are some random things I did (simultaneously for some stupid reason so I’m not sure which thing worked) and now the problem is solved.

1. Opened up “Chrome Extensions Management” page.
2. Opened up [Fiddler](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fiddler/hkknfnifmbannmgkdliadghepbneplka?hl=en) (which hadn’t been opened in weeks, and I have restarted Chrome many times without Fiddler open).
3. In Chrome under “Developer Mode” I hit “update extensions now.”
4. With Fiddler open, now GitHub works.
5. And now for the kicker. With Fiddler **closed** GitHub works again. I am sure Fiddler is not running right now and I have restarted Chrome to verify. It's working. Why would this only affect GitHub?

Answer (score 0):

Today I had the same problem. I am using a proxy server, and it looks like chrome wasn't able to verify the certificate via the proxy server. Because after getting a direct internet connection, it was working again. Now it keeps working even if I use the proxy again.

Answer (score 0):

This happened me because of AVG Safe Search Chrome extension, then I disabled this extension in chrome extensions and GitHub appeared as normal.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem today, too, it worked in Firefox, failed in Chrome (21.0.1180).

Simply clearing the Chrome browsing cache fixed it.

Don't know why it broke in the first place, perhaps it's something related to my company VPN?

Answer (score 0):

Because the problem seemed to persist across multiple devices, all on the same Chrome profile, it dawned on me it was the extension 'Allow-Control-Allow-Origin: *' as this was a common denominator. Once CORS had been turned off (didn't need to disable the plugin or anything) GitHub loads and works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem while I was using nod32 antivirus. Then, I figured that the problem was in the web access protection in the antivirus settings. I deactivated it and the website returned to work. So, check your antivirus web access protection and deactivate it.